# Uploading an image to Imgur

Tags: java, performance

I have made a class what uploads an image to imgur (a service with an API where you can upload images). And then I read the response of the API what contains the URL and the HTTP status code (200 if succeeded).

And I'd like some feedback, since the runtime is pretty long for a 50kb image. The current runtime is around 2,5 seconds. Isn't that a little too much or am I overestimating?

```
    public boolean connect() {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL(getApi());
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        final ScreenedImage image = new ScreenedImage();
        image.create();
        final String data = image.getData();

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.setRequestMethod(RequestMethod.POST);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("%s %s", request, clientId));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.connect();

        final OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();

        int bytesRead;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) > 0) {
            buffer.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        buffer.flush();

        final StringReader sr = new StringReader(buffer.toString());

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        final JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(sr);

        response = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);

        osw.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

ScreenedImage:

```
private BufferedImage image = null;
private File file = null;
private String data = null;

public void create() {
    try {
        file = new File("placeholder.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(file);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteArray);
        final byte[] imageByte = byteArray.toByteArray();
        final String dataImage = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageByte);
        final URLCodec codec = new URLCodec("UTF-8"); //apache codec library
        data = String.format("%s=%s", codec.encode("image"), codec.encode(dataImage));
    } catch (IOException | EncoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```